# How to mark reset attachments from SMTP server

Tags: java, android, smtp, jakarta-mail

How can I mark and reset the inpustream of attachments file from SMTP server for multiple reuse later?Any suggestions will be welcome.

Comment: The question here isn't at all clear, although your comment below clarifies it a bit.  If you have a BufferedInputStream for the attachment, just read it and copy it to wherever you want to save it, and then create an InputStream that refers to the saved copy for use in the message you're sending.  Or create a copy in memory using another byte array.  Without more detail of exactly what you're doing, it's hard to suggest the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

you are not willing to create the service now, I think you are stuck with the scenario you describe. There are some things though you could do to circumvent the problem of no user firing up the client anymore while there are still pending messages.

You could add a commandline utility that will only check for pending messages and try to send them.

Add this commandline utility to the StartUp folder or Run key in the registry. This way messages will at least get sent when the computer restarts, even if the user does not fire up the your app.

Add a scheduled task to run this utility at least once every day. The scheduled task can be added by code or by your installer.

If you do both, you will only have to worry about pending messages of users that never start their computer again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!In fact I develop an android mail application to send, receive email, and I want to save in BufferedInputstream the inpustream of the attachment for use later bacause firstly I store the mail localy inside of device for review later even device isn't connected that's the reason why I want to reuse the inputsream of the attachment!Is another scenario exist?

Comment: The answer above doesn't seem to have anything to do with this question...