# Is it possible to mirror attachments files from mail server using javamail

Tags: java, android, email, jakarta-mail

How can I do a mirroring of attachments files from mail server in java?Because I want to store local the mail without attachment and when my application has a connection(internet) so that's the reason why I want to use the mirroring of the attachment file!Any ideas will be welcome.

Comment: What is this about? Dont understand a word.

Comment: It's about email application in android, I want to synchronize the attachment when my app has a internet.

Comment: Synchronize? With what? You could explain things better i think. No idea where you are talking about. Yes it is about an email and an attachment. But what?

Comment: Synchronize the url of attachment or the inputsream for each attachment for using later.For example when I connect to internet then I can download the attachment, else I can't download attachment

Comment: Indeed you cannot doenload an attachment if you have no internet connection. In fact you cannot download anything then. Am i missing something? I still have no idea where this is all about.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40990095/how-to-mark-reset-attachments-from-smtp-server)?  What do you mean by "mirroring"?  Do you just want a copy of the attachment on the device?

Comment: @BillShannon yes I want a copy of the inputstream of the attachment for multiple use later(e.g download, redownload)

Comment: So copy it and save it.

Comment: Can you show me example code please!cause I've tried and it returned 0 byte when I reuse later